# Custome object detection on webcame

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, cmake

I try to run the custom face detection model locally on ubuntu 20
but when I run the script I got this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webcam_detection.py", line 104, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (1200,900)))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-h2062vqd/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:651: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

Here is my script:

```
######## Object Detection for Image #########
# 
# Author: Khai Do
# Date: 9/3/2019

## Some parts of the code is copied from Tensorflow object detection
## https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb


# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import zipfile
import cv2
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# Define the video stream
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Change only if you have more than one webcams

# What model
directPath = os.getcwd()
print(directPath)
MODEL_NAME = 'fine_tune_graph'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'object-detection.pbtxt')
# Number of classes to detect
NUM_CLASSES = 1


# Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


# Loading label map
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(
    label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


# Helper code
def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
    (im_width, im_height) = image.size
    return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
        (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


# Detection
with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        while True:

            # Read frame from camera
            ret, image_np = cap.read()
            # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
            image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
            # Extract image tensor
            image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
            # Extract detection boxes
            boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
            # Extract detection scores
            scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
            # Extract detection classes
            classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
            # Extract number of detectionsd
            num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
                'num_detections:0')
            # Actual detection.
            (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
                [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
                feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
            # Visualization of the results of a detection.
            vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np,
                np.squeeze(boxes),
                np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                np.squeeze(scores),
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                line_thickness=8)

            # Display output
            cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (1200,900)))

            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
```

Comment: It looks like your OpenCV installation does not have any kind of GUI support, how did you install OpenCV and its python binding?

Comment: the answer to your question is very clear.  Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'